# wp_new_user_notification not triggered

Tags: php, wordpress

I am testing a simple function, to get the **wp_new_user_notification** email to send, but the standard ordpress function is not triggering.

I'm not trying to change the function, I just want to trigger it.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
function test_new_user_email() {
    wp_new_user_notification ( '2', null, 'both' );
}
```

...which is as per:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/

In this case, I'm testing the sending of the email to an existing User ID = 2

As far as I can tell, it doesn't look like there are any dependencies on this standard function, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)? Try using that function to send an email to admin and/or the user with the ID of 2.

Comment: I did check that @sally, as I have other notifications that I'm receiving from wordpress without issue

Comment: Does it work with `$notify` set to `admin`, `user`, or empty (i.e. '')? E.g. `wp_new_user_notification( 2, null, 'user' )`. And the user actually (still) exists, right?..

Comment: i tried your suggestions Sally, still no luck sorry!

Comment: I wonder how did you call `test_new_user_email()`; is it from within a filter callback? Can you share the entire code?

Comment: You can also test this: [https://pastebin.com/S4Kd4mTk](https://pastebin.com/S4Kd4mTk)

Comment: ok great, that works now sally - thanks. only issue is that i'm getting a white screen now, upon accessing the front end URL

Comment: the full plugin is actually here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/
in file: import-users-from-csv.php
on line: 327
code is: wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $userdata['user_pass'] );
...but this is deprecated, so i replaced it with:
wp_new_user_notification ( $user_id, null, 'user' );
...but this doesn't work either

Comment: Actually that code snippet I shared on Pastebin.com, *it was just for testing purposes* to see if the `wp_new_user_notification()` function actually works. Now that we know it works, please remove the code from that file (*and you may also need/want to delete the dummy users created via the code*).

Comment: And sorry for saying this, but you really should consider using another plugin such as [*Import users from CSV with meta*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/). But then, if you really must fix the [*Import Users from CSV*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/) plugin, just let me know.

Comment: i tried the Import with meta plugin, but its very heavy for what I need really, and the admin UI screen has a lot going on (i have simple users :-). really appreciate your input tho

Comment: looking through the code of the Import with meta plugin... in file importer.php from line 463, there seems to be custom functions that send the notification, but using no standard WP functions (except for changing password & email address notifications - but not sending the initial email)

Comment: Please see the answer I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified version of the core file for "[Import Users from CSV](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-users-from-csv/)": [import-users-from-csv.php](https://pastebin.com/FJcGGZGy).

Note that it's not a full upgrade; I modified it just to make sure it's warnings-free (i.e. it passes `WP_DEBUG` "on" mode); and secondly, I've tested the "*Send to new users*" option (which uses the `wp_new_user_notification()` function), and it worked well.

In line 354, you can, if you want, set the 3rd argument to `both`:

```
if ( $new_user_notification )
    wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'user' );
```

Try [that new file](https://pastebin.com/FJcGGZGy) — download and upload it to *wp-content/plugins/import-users-from-csv/* — and just let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: so i've done some extensive testing here, and i'm not anywhere closer. i have a test environment & prod environment, i disabled all plugins on my test environment, except for the Import CSV plugin - still didn't work. then i updated the import-users-from-csv.php with your version, still no luck. The only plugin that I didn't disable, is this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp, which i use to override the WP mail - i use this plugin as it connects (via SMTP) to my Gmail account, which acts as the sender for all outbound notifications. All notifications work, except the CSV imports

Comment: I also found some arbitrary option_names & option_values in my wp_2_options table, I assume from old plugins, so I deleted them, but that didn't help either. I can't think of anything else in my setup that would stop this notification, when all other notifications are sending fine. Very strange. ps: thank you for your php file update :-)

Comment: Wow, why the heck it doesn't work on your end?? Haha. I mean, I've tried the WP Mail SMTP plugin, and I didn't get any problems; the users were imported/added successfully, and they (the email addresses) were notified without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `WP_DEBUG` and also checking the default *error_log* file? Does the problem happen on both or just one of the test and production environments? How about you create a 3rd environment; install WordPress with all the default/standard configurations (options, themes, etc.), and then install the "Import Users from CSV" and the WP Mail SMTP plugins. Then test the CSV users import plugin.

Comment: I know its killing me too! extremely frustrating! My debug shows this:
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in LearnDash_Course_Full_Progress_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use __construct() instead. in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3902. Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in OLT_Section_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3902

Comment: Whats also interesting, is that I tried this in my production environment too, and I'm getting the exact same issue! They are on different servers / instances, but with the same hosting (Google Cloud Compute). I'll try setup a 3rd environment, maybe I'll try my local machine instead & see what happens

Comment: About the debug notices, I think the plugins need to be updated. But even if you update them, I don't think it will solve the problem (with the CSV users import plugin). *Please let me know how it goes with the 3rd environment.*

Comment: ok... i think I've found the solution! there is a setting in the WP SMTP plugin, to choose from WP SMTP, or WP Mail - I changed this to WP Mail ... AND IT NOW WORKS! see here: https://imgur.com/a/3IOVf - whats strange though, is its allowing ALL other notifications, but not the new user one... URGHH!!

Comment: but thank you for your superstar help Sally, much appreciated! you're a WP legend :-). ps: put some contact details on your profile, and we can chat about some other projects that I'm working on (if you like), cheers!

Comment: Phew, I can finally sleep tight tonight! Lol. Well, I did want to ask you to disable the WP Mail SMTP plugin; however, the plugin didn't give me any issues, so I thought we can keep it enabled. Except, it seems that you're still using an older version of that plugin? Because I'm seeing a different settings page on my *localhost*. =) Nonetheless, I'm glad you found a solution!

Comment: actually, as you say that, you are right - i am using an older version, i'll update it & maybe i can keep my SMTP setting, instead of WP Mail!

Comment: Like many other people have said, always keep WordPress and your site up-to-date. Even just a test site that you'd actually delete soon. =) So good luck!

Comment: FYI - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-user-emails-not-sending-2/
I've logged a support issue with the plugin author